# VueJS 2 issue while compiling template

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

Im using TS with Vue.js **2.6.14**

I have a parent component in which i pass `billing` object as props to the `<ThirdStep/>` component. Im also using emitted function from that child component. In the child component i created a method called `onBillingChange` and connected it to each input (only one shown on the example code). However i get an error in that **child** component:

**Error:**

How to solve this?

```
    Module Error (from ./node_modules/@vue/vue-loader-v15/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js):
    (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)
    
      Errors compiling template:
    
      invalid expression: Unexpected identifier in
    
        (event) => onBillingChange('name', (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
    
      Raw expression: @input="(event) => onBillingChange('name', (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)"
```

**Parent component:**

```
<template>
  <form>
    <ThirdStep
      :billing="form.billing"
      @update:billing="updateBilling"
     />
   </form>
 </template>
    
<script lang="ts">

import Vue from "vue";
import { BillingInfo } from "./ThirdStep/ThirdStep.utils";
import ThirdStep from "./ThirdStep/ThirdStep.vue";


export default Vue.extend({
  name: "FormComponent",
  components: {
    ThirdStep,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        billing: {
          name: "",
          surname: "",
          street: "",
          buildingNumber: "",
          apartmentNumber: "",
          postalCode: "",
          city: "",
          phone: "",
          email: "",
        },
      },
    };
  },

 methods: {
    updateBilling(updatedBilling: BillingInfo) {
      this.form.billing = updatedBilling;
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

**And a child component ThirdStep.vue:**

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div>
      <label for="name">Name: <span>*</span></label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="name"
        @input="(event) => onBillingChange('name', (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)" //ERROR
      />
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue, { PropType } from "vue";
import { BillingInfo } from "./ThirdStep.utils";

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "FormThirdStep",
  props: {
    billing: Object as PropType<BillingInfo>,
  },
  methods: {
    onBillingChange(key: string, value: string) {
      const updatedBilling = { ...this.billing, [key]: value };
      this.$emit("update:billing", updatedBilling);
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: remove the cast in `(event.target as HTMLInputElement).value` and just use `event.target.value`